# Nesting multiple tables/queries on export to XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, export, ms-access-2010

Is there any way to use the `Application.ExportXML` method to not only merge multiple queries, but to nest the queries inside each other?

For example, let's say I have three tables. I'm already able to use the `Application.ExportXML` method to merge the three together. The main queries that I don't want repeating don't repeat, and the one with all the customer info does. Good.

But it comes out like this (for various paranoid reasons I'm using fake data):

```
<DogCare>
  <Facility>Twin Peaks</Facility>
  <Year>1992</Year>
  <Month>1</Month>
</DogCare>
<DogTeam>
  <Team>DogWalker</Team>
  <DogsWalked>24</DogsWalked>
  <TreatsGiven>900</TreatsGiven>
</DogTeam>
<PetWalkTime>
  <Name>Palmer</Name>
  <Age>7</Age>
  <FavoriteSnack>Cheese</FavoriteSnack>
  <FavThingtoDo>Chew Shoes</FavThingtoDo>
  <Day>1</Day>
  <DidBusiness>Yes</DidBusiness>
  <Barked>Constantly</Barked>
  <PulledonLeash>Whole Time</PulledonLeash>
  <DeservesTreat>Gave it Anyway</DeservesTreat>
</PetWalkTime>
<PetWalkTime>
  <Name>Laura</Name>
  <Age>5</Age>
  <FavoriteSnack>Pie</FavoriteSnack>
  <FavThingtoDo>Fetch</FavThingtoDo>
  <Day>1</Day>
  <DidBusiness>Yes</DidBusiness>
  <Barked>No</Barked>
  <PulledonLeash>No</PulledonLeash>
  <DeservesTreat>Gave Several</DeservesTreat>
</PetWalkTime>
```

Now. "DogCare","DogTeam", and "PetWalkTime" are separate queries. Yet, they are all related and belong within each other like so:

```
<DogCare>
  <Facility>Twin Peaks</Facility>
  <Year>1992</Year>
  <Month>2</Month>
  <DogTeam>
    <Team>DogWalker</Team>
    <DogsWalked>24</DogsWalked>
    <TreatsGiven>900</TreatsGiven>
    <PetWalkTime>
        <Name>Palmer</Name>
        <FavoriteSnack>Cheese</FavoriteSnack>
        <FavThingtoDo>Chew Shoes</FavThingtoDo>
        <Day>1</Day>
        <DidBusiness>Yes</DidBusiness>
        <Barked>Constantly</Barked>
        <PulledonLeash>Whole Time</PulledonLeash>
        <DeservesTreat>Gave it Anyway</DeservesTreat>
    </PetWalkTime>
    <PetWalkTime>
         <Name>Laura</Name>
         <FavoriteSnack>Pie</FavoriteSnack>
         <FavThingtoDo>Fetch</FavThingtoDo>
         <Day>1</Day>
         <DidBusiness>Yes</DidBusiness>
         <Barked>No</Barked>
         <PulledonLeash>No</PulledonLeash>
         <DeservesTreat>Gave Several</DeservesTreat>
    </PetWalkTime>
  </DogTeam>
</DogCare>
```

Is there any way to make that last one possible on export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Application.ExportXML` can export proper nested XML, provided that

1. you are exporting Tables (not Queries), and
2. you have set up Relationships in Access (a.k.a. foreign key constraints) between the tables

[image: Relationships.png]

If either of those conditions is not met then even if you use the method outlined in the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212%28v=office.15%29.aspx) you will still get "sequential" XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-11-21T13:43:50">
    <DogCare>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Facility>Twin Peaks</Facility>
    </DogCare>
    <DogTeam>
        <TeamID>1</TeamID>
        <ParentID>1</ParentID>
        <Team>DogWalker</Team>
    </DogTeam>
    <PetWalkTime>
        <WalkID>1</WalkID>
        <TeamID>1</TeamID>
        <Name>Palmer</Name>
        <Age>7</Age>
    </PetWalkTime>
    <PetWalkTime>
        <WalkID>2</WalkID>
        <TeamID>1</TeamID>
        <Name>Laura</Name>
        <Age>5</Age>
    </PetWalkTime>
</dataroot>
```

However, if both conditions are met then we can get "nested" XML like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-11-21T13:52:50">
    <DogCare>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Facility>Twin Peaks</Facility>
        <DogTeam>
            <TeamID>1</TeamID>
            <ParentID>1</ParentID>
            <Team>DogWalker</Team>
            <PetWalkTime>
                <WalkID>1</WalkID>
                <TeamID>1</TeamID>
                <Name>Palmer</Name>
                <Age>7</Age>
            </PetWalkTime>
            <PetWalkTime>
                <WalkID>2</WalkID>
                <TeamID>1</TeamID>
                <Name>Laura</Name>
                <Age>5</Age>
            </PetWalkTime>
        </DogTeam>
    </DogCare>
</dataroot>
```

using code like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub XmlExportTest()
    Dim objTeam As AdditionalData, objWalk As AdditionalData
    Set objTeam = Application.CreateAdditionalData
    Set objWalk = objTeam.Add("DogTeam")
    objWalk.Add "PetWalkTime"
    Application.ExportXML _
            ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
            DataSource:="DogCare", _
            DataTarget:="C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\DogData.xml", _
            AdditionalData:=objTeam
End Sub
```